# Is there a way to see all chat rooms that you have ever used?

Tags: support, chat

I am looking for a way to quickly see all the chat rooms I've ever spoken in, without having to star each one to keep track of it. Is this something that is currently supported?

Comment: I'm afraid your only option is to scrape chat.stackoverflow.com....

Comment: Maybe you can do some trickery with search http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248541/158100

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1332389/tarehman?tab=recent is probably a reasonable starting point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not *quickly*. There is no entry point that enables us mortals to get to that data, although you can see on your usercard in how many rooms you ever talked:

[image: user card with nuber of rooms]

To know which rooms that are we can only scrape the server. This script does that if you visit your  chat [usercard](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1332389/tarehman?tab=recent).

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         chat entries search
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  search all rooms for your messages
// @author       rene
// @match        https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

var backlog = [], // holds all functions to be executed
    interval,     // interval handle
    user = parseInt(/.*\.com\/users\/(\d+)\/.*/.exec(document.location)[1], 10); // which user

// parse the events array for the current user_id
function handleEvents(events) {
    var i,
        found = false;
    for(i = 1; i < events.length; i = i + 1) {
        if (events[i].user_id === user ) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

// handle a room, optionally for messages before a certain id
function handleRoom(room, roomName, before) {
    var data = {
            fkey: fkey().fkey,
            msgCount: 500,
            mode: 'Messages',
        };
     if (before) data.before = before;
     $.post('/chats/' + room + '/events',
        data,
        function(response) {
            if (response.events && response.events[0]) {
                // if the user if found
                if (handleEvents(response.events))
                {
                    // add a new link
                    $('#user-roomcards-container').append(
                        $('<div></div>').append(
                            $('<a></a>').prop('href','/rooms/' + room).text(roomName)
                            )
                    );
                } else {
                    // scan the remaining events
                    backlog.push(function() { handleRoom(room, roomName, response.events[0].message_id); });
                }    
            }
     });
}

// handle all rooms on page
function handleRooms(page) {
    var maxrooms = 0;
    // get 60 rooms sorted on activity
    $.post('/rooms', 
        {tab:'all', sort:'active',pageSize:60, page:page,nohide:true}, 
        function (data) { 
            $(data).find('.room-header').each(function () { 
                var roomLink = $(this).find('a'),
                    room = parseInt(/.*\/(\d+)\/.*/.exec(roomLink.prop('href'))[1],10);
                maxrooms++;
                if (room !== NaN) {
                    backlog.push( function () { handleRoom(room, roomLink.text()); }); 
                }
            }); 
        // as long as we found 60 rooms ...
        if (maxrooms === 60) {
           // ... fetch the next page with rooms
           backlog.push( function () {handleRooms(page + 1); });
        }
    });
}

// start working
backlog.push(function () {handleRooms(1); });

// takes a fuinction from the backlog 
// every 4 seconds
interval = setInterval(function() { 
    var f = backlog.shift();
    if (f === undefined ) {
         $('#user-roomcards-container').append($('<div></div>').text('done!'));
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        f();
    }
}, 4000);
```

If you let this run a while it will add links to your currently in rooms list:

[image: where you ever talked]

By the looks of it I talk Trash as well. I let it run for a full day, it didn't find my [74 rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDaGR.png) but I'm not going to hunt down that bug...

The script is tested with Tampermonkey on Google Chrome. You could get throttled if you are very active chatting as well while the script is running.

Comment: *must. click...*